# Flutter doctor is not working

Tags: flutter

```
C:\Windows\system32>flutter doctor
```

> Unhandled exception: ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32
>   application.

Command: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}

Comment: got stuck here while creating flutter environment..........please help

Comment: i think there is some issue with my git.....please help me resolve it

Comment: @Peter i tried it but still ended with the same .... my error part is somewhat around git.exe as shown above

Comment: still waiting for further suggestions

Comment: now i ended with this                                                                                             Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: 2c42b694a4269e30)
CreateProcessW failed 193
Unhandled exception:
ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

  Command: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.EXE -version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572494/flutter-doctor-is-not-working/51574697 Try this link..could be helpful

Comment: Try this instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572494/flutter-doctor-is-not-working/51574697

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a potential issues involving tooling/Android SDK paths with spaces. Per [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19359#issuecomment-445359366):

> Moving some recent discussion over from
> [#9976](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9976) (older issue):
>
> Potential issues involve tooling/Android SDK paths with spaces. We
> currently run all CI with spaces in the SDK path. Since we build the
> Gallery example (which is nested under the SDK), we're also covering
> the case where the user Flutter project directory contains a space.
>
> Other issues I can imagine that AFAIK we don't test for in our CI, but
> probably should:
>
> - Space in Android SDK path (all OSes)
> - Space in Xcode path (on macOS)
> - Space in path of command-line tools such as ideviceinstaller, git, etc. (all OSes)

And looks like this issue [was resolved by the Dart SDK fix](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19359#issuecomment-523064688) that was landed in master channel.